# different screen size in interactive whiteboard application

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, socket.io

I'm developing an interactive whiteboard application (you draw something, and other peers see in real-time what you are drawing). I'm using html5 canvas.

However, people on the same whiteboard might each have different screen sizes, and different width/height ratio. Hence, some part may appear cut on someone's screen.

How do you tackle this kind of problem? (one solution i thought is using SVG to render drawing instead of canvas, this way you can "scroll down" to see more elements if they are cut...)

Answer (score 5):

All canvas rendering is done by first multiplying all coordinates by a transformation matrix. This matrix scales, translates, rotates, skews, shears, and more all in one operation on every pixel you render.

All you have to do is set the transform to fit the common drawing area onto the canvas. Because aspects are different for different displays you will have to scale to a fit the white board.

Thus if your whiteboard is

```
var whiteBoard = {
     width : 1000,
     height : 500,
}
```

And you have a canvas size

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth; // or whatever page size you want
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

to fit the white board get the min scale to fit

```
var scale = Math.min(canvas.width / whiteBoard.width, canvas.height / whiteboard.height);
```

then get the top left corner

```
var top = canvas.height / 2  - (whiteBoard.height * scale) / 2;
var left = canvas.width / 2 - (whiteBoard.width * scale) / 2;
```

Then you set the transform

```
ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,left,top);
```

Now you can draw on the canvas with the same coordinates on all the displays.

```
ctx.fillRect(0,0,whiteBoard.width,whiteBoard.height);
```

will be displayed not matter the screen size or aspect and nothing will be missing and it will be display as large as possible without clipping.

Comment: then in this case, users have to exchange information about their screen sizes to each other, right?

Comment: @user42624 No you need to define a standard whiteboard size that everyone will use. When someone draws on the canvas. subtract the top.left from the mouse coordes and divide by the scale. This will convert the mouse coord to standard whiteboard scale and position. Nobody needs to know the screen size of others.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy solution: Make the canvas size fixed

More clever solution: You might be able to use the scale attribute to fit the canvas into the required window size. Then users with small screens can simply zoom in and out to view the entire canvas